# Tensor rotation confunsion with indexes

Tags: tensors

I am curious about how to rotate a tensor from one system of coordinates to another. The relation that I try to understand is:

$T^{'}_{ij}=L_{ik}L_{ji}T_{kl}$ (1) ------> where $T^{'}_{ij}$ is the new system of coordinates   $T_{kl}$ is the old one, right?

As far as I know $L$ is the rotation matrix. In this case, there are two matrices. If I want to do a rotation around Z axis L should be:

$L= \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)&0\\
  -sin(\theta)&cos(\theta)&0\\
   0&0&1
\end{array}
\right] $

My question is:

- I only have one matrix rotation $L$. But in (1) two L's: $L_{ik}$ and $L_{jk}$ each other. How they are related?

*How can find the index $_{kl}$ in order to find the $T_{ij}$ components of the tensor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Index counting spots a typo, corrected viz. $T_{ij}^\prime=L_{ik}L_{j\color{blue}{l}}T_{kl}$, or in matrix terms$$T^\prime=LTL^T=LTL^{-1}.$$If $v^\prime:=Lv$ with a vector, $T^\prime v^\prime=LTv$.